# Radio buttons checked by default

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have an html page with a form in it. It has two radio buttons labelled <kbd>Day Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Night Shift</kbd>. I have a  JavaScript IF else statement that says if the current time is later than 7:00 and before 19:00 then auto-default the dayshift button to be checked else check the Night Shift button.

I don't understand how to have the radio buttons be checked based off this statement. I have  put a value into a JavaScript variable before from a radio button, but not the other way around. Any help is most appreciated.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
      <script src="Scripts/autoRadio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Design.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="WasteEntry.asp" method="post">
         <fieldset>
            <input type="radio" required name="Shift" id="dayShift" value="Day Shift" >
            <input type="radio"  name="Shift" id="eveningShift" value="Evening Shift" >
         </fieldset>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
 var now = new Date().getHours();
if (now > 7 && now < 19) {
     document.getElementById('dayShift').checked = true;
} else {
     document.getElementById('eveningShift').checked = true;
}
```

Comment: fyi, you have `required` twice on your radio buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var now = new Date().getHours();
if (now > 7 && now < 19) {
     document.getElementById('dayShift').checked = true;
} else {
     document.getElementById('eveningShift').checked = true;
}
```

PS: You really should change the invalid duplicate IDs. And the `required` attribute should not be duplicated either.

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand about the duplicate id's. I named one dayShift and the other eveningShift for my id's. How is this duplicate? Are you referring to my <td>'s.?   I have tried the code and the buttons are not reacting

Comment: I meant the `formBody` ones, it is not related to your problem, I just mentioned it.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Did not work for me, are you able to put it on jsfiddle?

Comment: I see it working in jsfidde, but for some reason it does not work on my html page. I even simplified it but its not auto checking. What do you think is going on? Is it my ordering to the links? am I missing something?

Comment: needed a window.onload =function () {}

Answer (score 5):

This should do it.

```
var now= new Date().getHours();
if(now>7 && now<19){
    radiobtn = document.getElementById("dayShift");
    radiobtn.checked = true;
} else{
    radiobtn = document.getElementById("eveningShift");
    radiobtn.checked = true; 
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Are you able to put it on jsfiddle?